# Which is correct "efforts have been devoted to achieving strength " or " efforts have been devoted to achieve strength

Tags: grammar

I have been told to replace "have been devoted to achieving" with "have been devoted to achieve". Can you explain why?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

You are misinformed: *devoted to achieving* is correct.

The *to* here is not an infinitive marker but a preposition which *devote* requires to designate the matter to which its Patient is devoted; the object of the preposition is a nominal, either a noun phrase or a free relative clause or a gerund (*-ing* form) clause:

> She devoted her efforts **to** the cause she believed in.
> She devoted her efforts **to** what she believed in.
> She devoted her efforts **to** promoting her cause.
>
> Her efforts were devoted **to** the cause she believed in.
> Her efforts were devoted **to** what she believed in.
> Her efforts were devoted **to** promoting her cause.

*Devote* does not license infinitival complements.